# how to use data that is sent through the post or get request with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to jQuery .I want to send the data from `form.html` to `info.html`.I found one snippet which posts the data to `info.html` but I have no idea how to this data in `info.html`

**Form.html**

```
var arr = {
    City: 'Moscow', 
    Age:25
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'delete2.html',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('body').html(JSON.stringify(data));
    },   
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
        console.log(errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

But I want to use that data and use the `City` and `Age` in `info.html`. I know that can be done in PHP, something like this by including `form.html` and `$_POST['cityName']`, but how can I do this in jQuery? I want to use the data that I have posted to `info.html`.

Comment: like sending `get` request can't I use the data from the url like this  `http://localhost/auth0/delete2.html?{"City":"Moscow","Age":25}` use the city variable in `info.html`?